# GStreamer branch manipulation

Tags: gstreamer

I have a pipeline in GStreamer of the following structure:

rtspsrc -> rtph264depay -> parser -> tee
-> queue -> (bin - MP4 file)
-> queue -> (bin - RTP/UDP)

What I want to be able to is, on interrupt from bus, remove (or add) a specified branch.

I'm following the gstreamer [guide](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf), section 19.4

When the pipeline first starts playing all is well and everything plays how it should. My issue is that when I add a branch, its elements don't get to the PLAYING state. They get as far as PAUSED, except for the last element which remains at READY. I've tried keeping the queue on the tee and unlinking the bin from the queue.

When I tried putting the queue in the bin and linking/unlinking from the tee, I had issues removing the bin even after blocking the branch and sending an EOS.

How should I go about doing this dynamic branch manipulation?

EDIT: setting async=false allows the elements in the branch to go to PLAYING but the bin [queue -> imxvpudec -> imxipuvideotransform -> videorate -> capsfilter -> imxvpuenc_h264 -> rtph264pay -> udpsink] won't link to the tee. Trying to link to the pad retrieved using gst_element_get_compatible_pad() returns GST_PAD_LINK_NOFORMAT.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't understand your question, especially when considering the tags you set.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of places where this kind of pipeline can go wrong.  Do you explicitly set the state to "playing" when you add the new branch?   Could you paste the full details of the pipeline including your mux and parse elements and the attributes on the bin elements?

Comment: The "not going to PLAYING" bit is fixed, that was just a matter of setting async=false for all sinks.

I'm using h264parse as my parser and mpegtsmux as my multiplexer. However, for now I only want to consider the udpsink branch, the problem also occurs when there's a fakesink in place of the file branch. 

I'm also decoding/encoding in the udpsink branch, using imxvpudec and imxvpuenc_h264.

The issue I now face is that when linking the udpsink branch:
queue -> imxvpudec -> imxipuvideotransform -> videorate -> capsfilter -> imxvpuenc_h264 -> rtph264pay -> udpsink
, data isn't being sent

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of elements in the branch going to PAUSED but not PLAYING, except the sink which goes as far as READY, setting the "async" property of the sink to "false" was required.

Regarding the link error, for some reason when linking tee -> branch, the Caps of the tee source (found using "gst_element_get_compatible_pad()") were not the same as the source of the preceding element (the parser). As a result, when the branch sink wanted caps and queried the tee, which queried the element behind, the branch sink got the same caps as the parser source, which was incompatible with the tee source. This was fixed (in my case) by putting the parser AFTER the tee (on the branch) rather than before it. I do not know the cause of this, but it works now.